# Events on Ivy Bridge with PAPI

Tags: papi

I'm using `PAPI` to do some measurement and characteristic work, I've got several questions about the events on Ivy Bridge.

1. Based on the SDM Table 19-5 (Non-Architectural Performance Events In the Processor Core of 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ i7, i5, i3 Processors), the Ivy Bridge has counters named `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_LDM_PENDING`, `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_PENDING` and `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L2_PENDING`. However, when I tried `papi_native_avail`, I got not only these three but also corresponding `STALLS` events for each one, including `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_LDM_PENDING`, `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING` and `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING`. And I've also got different numbers with `CYCLES` and `STALLS` events. So the question is what is the difference between them.
2. This question is related to the above one, because in the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual Appendix B.3.2.3 all the events mentioned are `STALLS` events, which are not even mentioned in the SDM actually, rather than `CYCLES` events. And the question is what are they supposed to be, `CYCLES` or `STALLS`? And which ones should I use to do the memory bound characterization as B.3.2.3 mentioned?
3. There are some formulas in the Appendix B.3.2.3 mentioned above about how to calculate the bound on different level of memory subsystem. One thing I found confusing is that when I did measurement using STALLS events mentioned above, I got larger number on `STALLS_L2_PENDING` than `STALLS_L1D_PENDING`, while there is a formula in that section shows:

`%L2 Bound = (CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING - CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING) / CLOCKS`

Does this mean my measurement is wrong? If not, then how could I calculate `%L2 Bound` since it would be above zero.

The source code is on the following link:
https://github.com/yqzhang/SMTM/blob/master/native/native.c

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: I didn't know exactly the difference between the STALLS_ AND CYCLES_ events, if you figured it out please let me know. However there are indeed both events on Ivy Bridge, seems that the SDM is outdated, as you can use vtune to measure both events.

Comment: your github link is wrong